# ¿como aparecer un modal después de validar un registro en php?

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Tengo un formulario de registro en html y después guardo estos campos con archivo de php, lo que necesito es que después de insertar los datos me aparezca un modal o una ventana emergente que me avise que los datos han sido ingresados correctamente; ahora lo hago con alert, pero necesito que me salga un cuadro y no una alerta, gracias les dejo mi código

html

```
<form action="guardarpaciente.php" method="post">
  <div class="formularioregistro">   
    <legend>DATOS PERSONALES DATOS CLINICOS</legend>       
    <div id="tipo_Documento">
      <select>
        <option>Tipo de documento</option>
        <option value="dni">DNI</option>
        <option value="pn">PN</option>
        <option value="ce">CE</option>
        <option value="sd">SD</option>              
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="txtDni">
      <input type="text" name="dni" maxlength="8" required placeholder="Numero de documento" autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%;">
    </div>

    <div id="tipo_tratamiento">
      <select>
      <?php while ( $row = $resultado_titratamiento->fetch_array() )    
      { ?>
        <option value=" <?php echo $row['cod_tip_tratamiento'] ?>">
          <?php echo $row['nombre_tipo_tratamiento']; ?>
        </option>    
      <?php
      } ?> 
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor4">    
      <div id="txtnombre">  
        <input type="text" name="nombre"  required placeholder="Nombre"   autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%; width: 128%;" >          
      </div>
      <div id="txtapellidop">
        <input type="text" name="apellidop"  required placeholder="Apellido Paterno"   autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
      </div>
      <div id="txtapellidom">
        <input type="text" name="apellidom"  required placeholder="Apellido Materno"   autocomplete="off"  style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
      </div>
      <div id="condicioningreso">
        <select id="comobocingreso" >
        <?php while ( $row = $resultado_ingreso->fetch_array() )    
        { ?>
          <option value=" <?php echo $row['cod_cingreso'] ?>">
            <?php echo $row['nombre_condicion_ingreso']; ?>
          </option>
        <?php
        } ?>      
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor7">
      <div id="fchanacimiento">
        <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
        <input name="user_date" id="user_date" type="date" name="fechanac"   autocomplete="off" onchange="calcularedad()" style="height: 20%;width: 128%;">
      </div>
      <div id="edad">
        <label id="edad"></label>    
      </div>
      <div id="txtnumerocaso">
        <input type="text" name="numero_de_caso" required placeholder="Numero de caso" autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%;" >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id=contenedor12>
      <div id="sexo">
        <select>
          <option>Sexo</option>
          <option value="M">Masculino</option>
          <option value="F">Femenino</option>                             
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="historiacli">
        <input type="text" name="historia" required placeholder="Numero de historia clinica" autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%; margin-top:0px; margin-left: -70px;" >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor5">
      <div id="talla">
        <input type="text" name="talla" required placeholder="Talla"  autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;"> 
      </div>
      <div id="peso">
        <input type="text" name="peso" autocomplete="off" required  placeholder="Peso" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor6">
      <div id="telefono">
        <input type="number" name="telefono" required placeholder="telefono"  autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
      </div>
      <div id="celular">
        <input type="number" name="celular" required  placeholder="celular"  autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor8">
      <select id="pais">
        <option>Pais</option>
        <option>Peru</option>
        <option>Uruguay</option>
      </select>
      <select id="departamento">
        <option>Departamento</option>
        <option>Peru</option>
        <option>Uruguay</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <select id="provincia">
      <option>Provincia</option>
      <option>Peru</option>
      <option>Uruguay</option>
    </select>

    <select id="distrito">
      <option>Distrito</option>
      <option>Peru</option>
      <option>Uruguay</option>
    </select>

    <div id="correo">
      <input type="text" name="correo" required placeholder="correo electronico" autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%; width: 38%;">
    </div> 
    <div id="direccion">
      <input type="text" name="direccion" required placeholder="Direcion"  autocomplete="off" style="height: 20%; width: 38%;">
    </div>
    <input id="btnguardar" type="submit" value="Guardar" name="Guardar" class="btn-enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

codigo php :

```
<?php 
 include '../conexionbd.php';

$dni=$_POST["dni"];
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$apellidop=$_POST["apellidop"];
$apellidom=$_POST["apellidom"];
$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
$celular=$_POST["celular"];
$localizacion='1';
$direccion=$_POST["direccion"];
$fechanacimiento=$_POST["fechanac"];
$correo=$_POST["correo"];
$nro_caso=$_POST["numero_de_caso"];
$nro_historia=$_POST["historia"];
$cod_ingreso=$_POST["condicioningreso"];
$fecha_activacion=date_default_timezone_set('Y-m-d');
$peso=$_POST["peso"];
$talla=$_POST["talla"];
$cod_situacion='1';

$verificar_paciente=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM persona where dni='$dni'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_paciente)>0){
    echo'
      <script>
    alert("El paciente ya se encuentra registrado");
    window.history.go(-1);
      </script>
    ';
    exit;
}

$insertar_paciente="INSERT INTO persona(dni,nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,sexo,telefono,celular,cod_localizacion,direccion,fecha_de_nacimiento,correo_electronico) values ('$dni','$nombre','$apellidop','$apellidom','$sexo','$telefono','$celular','$localizacion','$direccion','$fechanacimiento','$correo')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar_paciente);

if($resultado){
    echo "<script>
     alert('correcto');
     window.location.href('crear_esquema.php');
     </script>
    ";
}else{
    echo "<script>
     alert('correcto');
     </script>
    ";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);



 ?>
```

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí: el código compartido presenta problemas graves de seguridad y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público. Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP.

Comment: ¿Usas bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes generar un modal como este :

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Agregado exitosamente</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aunque seria lo mejor que hicieras el POST mediante ajax

Comment: me podrias dar una referencia de como hacerlo por json porfavor